# macOS packet filter (port forwarding)

Tags: macos, firewall, proxy

I am trying to redirect the outbound traffic to destination port 80 to the local proxy port 127.0.0.1:8080 without success

/etc/pf.anchors/com.forwarding

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

/etc/pf.conf

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "myproxy"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
load anchor "myproxy" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.forwarding"
```

Then:

```
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.conf
```

The local traffic 127.0.0.1:80 is redirected to 127.0.0.1:8080, but not the external, the one towards internet.

Comment: For anyone that doesn’t need to artisanaly build a proxy from the ground up so they can master all the parts, there’s an app for this: https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Thank you, but my purpose is not the proxy itself, but the most important thing is to make this rule work.

Comment: Excellent - I just wanted people looking for an easy proxy to have that option. Knowledge is powerful and deep knowledge if this networking means you can do so many other things. Looking forward to an answer and perhaps to learn something myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only redirect **incoming** traffic. Any outgoing traffic to port 80 isn't affected by your rdr rule.

To redirect outgoing traffic to port 80 you have to re-route it first to lo0 then redirect it to the proxy port:

The order in the config file is necessarily *rdr incomming packets*, then *filter packets* (like pass), but chronologically the 2nd rule will hit first (on en0), which will then activate the first rule (on lo0).

```
# Step "2". redirect those same packets that were routed to lo0 below
rdr pass log on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
# Step "1". Route new IPv4 TCP connections leaving en0 to lo0
pass out on en0 route-to lo0 proto tcp from en0 to any port 80 keep state
```

in pf.conf this would look like this:

```
...
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr pass log on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
pass out on en0 route-to lo0 proto tcp from en0 to any port 80 keep state
```

In the above example I assume en0 is your only outbound *en* interface.

Unload your current pf.conf and stop pf: `sudo pfctl -d`. Then add the two additional lines above. After modifying pf.conf check the syntax of the file with `sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf` which should result in the following output:

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

scrub-anchor "/*" all fragment reassemble
nat-anchor "/*" all
rdr-anchor "/*" all
rdr pass log on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
anchor "/*" all
pass out on en0 route-to lo0 proto tcp from en0 to any port 80 flags S/SA keep state
dummynet-anchor "/*" all
```

and if successful load it with `sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf`.

---

A proper system and proxy configuration (and well-behaving apps) don't require such pf rules!

Comment: Yeah! it works, many thanks for your explanations, it helps me a lot.